# Pass object to isolated directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my application loads a function to get items from a server runs, this function get the title and Id of all items on the server,
then puts them in an array.

In my main html I have a table that displays this array, and when i click the title of an Item, I call another function (onView)
which gathers more information about that item from the server. This new information is passed to
a variable called '$scope.currentItem'.

I also have a directive called 'currentItem', this is used to display that item for the user.

```
myApp.directive('currentItem',function(){
  return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
        data:'='
    },
    templateUrl: 'currentItem.html',
    controller:function($scope){
    }
  };
});
```

To know if a user has clicked an item I have a boolean called isView, so when the function to gather more information runs
the isView is set to 'true'.

My html looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<hr>
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">

    <div ng-hide="isView" class="col-md-12">
        <table id="mainTable" ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
            <tbody  ng-repeat="item in items">
                <tr>
                    <td id="Title"  data-title="'Title'">
                        {{item.id}} |<a ng-click="onView(item.id)">{{item.title}}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="'Description'">
                        {{item.description | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
                    </td>

                    <td  data-title="'Created'">
                        {{item.created | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="isView" class="col-md-12">
        <current-item data="currentItem"></current-item>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This can't be the correct way to pass an object to a directive, seeing I always use the same 'currentItem' object.

How could I improve this, so that each object is isolated and editable in a seperate view?

Comment: This looks fine on first glance. You set `$scope.currentItem` when a user clicks on an item, which in turn will update the directive. What exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: Since the 'currentItem' is set this way, do I even need the directive? Can't I just update currentItem?

Comment: The directive is one way to display the data, so it is up to you if you want to package it in its own `html` file, or just put the html directly where you have the directive now.

Comment: So you think this is valid? I will build on this to edit the current item and such within the directive, so I really want them to be as isolated as possible